# Flash Object Dimensions in Firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, dimensions

I have a Flash Object on an html page where the Flash Object is of dimensions 960px by 540px.

For some reason Firefox is showing extra space around the Flash because it is showing the dotted line at around 1046px. This is only happening on Firefox, not on other browsers.

I am using Firefox 9.0.1.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does your flash object have any default margins or so?

Comment: Not in your CSS, but in the browsers default css rules. Sometimes default margins are applied, so you could try setting margin and padding to 0 explicitly. Is the extra space within the embedded SWF or is it outside of it?

Comment: turns out it was because I was using the debugger version of Flash Player 11

Comment: that sounds rather odd. so the extra space was within your swf?